# How to solve Bellman's optimal equation from the first principle

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, control-theory, decision-theory

How to solve the following set (finite) of equations

$$ v_*(s) = \max_{a\in A(s)} \sum_{s'} p(s'|s,a) [r(s,a,s') + \gamma v_*(s')]$$

$p$ and $r$ functions are given.

Answer (score 0):

Since $$
\sum_{s'} p(s'|s,a) [r(s,a,s') + \gamma v_*(s')]
$$ is a function of $a$ and $s$, we can denote it as $g(a,s)$ we can consider 
$$
\max_a g(a,s)
$$
as a parametric optimization in $a$. If you assume that $s$ has discrete values only, it is possible to solve the maximization problem for each possible $s$ separately.